# Unable to create Private Endpoint using the Azure SDK

Tags: java, azure, sdk, endpoint, azure-cli

Setup:

```
OS: MacOS with Apple chip
IDE: IntelliJ 2022.3.2
Libraries:
implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-core', version: '1.28.0'
implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-identity', version: '1.5.1'
implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-core-management', version: '1.10.1'
implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-resourcemanager', version: '2.23.0'
```

Getting the following exception when attempting to create a private link service.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.azure.resourcemanager.network.models.ErrorException: Status code 400, "{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequestFormat",
    "message": "Cannot parse the request.",
    "details": []
  }
}": Cannot parse the request.
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:710)
    at com.azure.core.http.rest.ResponseExceptionConstructorCache.invoke(ResponseExceptionConstructorCache.java:56)
    at com.azure.core.http.rest.RestProxy.instantiateUnexpectedException(RestProxy.java:439)
    at com.azure.core.http.rest.RestProxy.lambda$ensureExpectedStatus$2(RestProxy.java:393)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMapMany.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.fastPath(FluxIterable.java:362)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:227)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onSubscribeInner(MonoFlatMapMany.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMapMany.java:245)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8466)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:195)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime.subscribeOrReturn(MonoCacheTime.java:151)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:292)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMapMany.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.fastPath(FluxIterable.java:362)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:227)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onSubscribeInner(MonoFlatMapMany.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMapMany.java:245)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8466)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:195)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:337)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onNext(MonoCacheTime.java:354)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDoFinally.java:128)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDoFinally.java:128)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:400)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:419)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:473)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:702)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1373)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1247)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1287)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1707)
```

Code used to create the private endpoint is:

```
public static void createPrivateEndpoint(com.azure.resourcemanager.AzureResourceManager azure) {
   PrivateEndpointInner privateEndpointInner = new PrivateEndpointInner()
       .withLocation("eastus")
       .withSubnet(
           new SubnetInner()
               .withId(
                   "/subscriptions/valid_subscription_ID/resourceGroups/valid_resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/valid_vnet/subnets/valid_subnet"))
       .withPrivateLinkServiceConnections(
           Arrays
               .asList(
                   new PrivateLinkServiceConnection()
                       .withPrivateLinkServiceId(
                           "/subscriptions/valid_subscription_ID/resourceGroups/valid_resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateLinkServices/valid_private_link_service")
                    ));
   azure.networks().manager().serviceClient().getPrivateEndpoints().createOrUpdate(
       "valid_resource_group_name",
       "valid_private_endpoint_name",
       privateEndpointInner,
       Context.NONE);
 }
```

I was able to create private endpoint using azure portal and azure cli. Even when I try to list the endpoints, it is working with SDK. Only create API is not working. Am I missing something?

Facing issue with the Azure SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue as you mentioned in the question.

After reproducing from my end with below code, I am able to create private end point:

```java
@RestController
public class AzureSdkController {
    static AzureProfile profile = new AzureProfile(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
    static TokenCredential credential = new EnvironmentCredentialBuilder()
            .authorityHost(profile.getEnvironment().getActiveDirectoryEndpoint()).build();
    static AzureResourceManager azure = AzureResourceManager.configure().authenticate(credential, profile)
            .withSubscription("<subscription_id>");

    @GetMapping("/create")
    public void createPrivateEndpoint() {
        azure.networks().manager().serviceClient().getPrivateEndpoints().createOrUpdate("rg1", "mypv1",
                new PrivateEndpointInner().withLocation("eastus").withSubnet(new SubnetInner().withId(
                        "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/myVnet/subnets/mySubnet"))
                        .withPrivateLinkServiceConnections(Arrays.asList(new PrivateLinkServiceConnection()
                                .withName("testPls")
                                .withPrivateLinkServiceId(
                                        "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateLinkServices/testPls")
                                .withGroupIds(Arrays.asList()).withRequestMessage("Please approve my connection"))));
    }

}
```

**Output:**

[image]